# How can I understand how this C++ merge sort code works?

Tags: c++, mergesort

```
template<class Type>
void linkedQueueType<Type>::mergeSort() {
    mergeSort(queueFront);
    if (queueFront == NULL) 
        queueRear = NULL;
    else {
        queueRear = queueFront;
        while (queueRear->link != NULL)
            queueRear = queueRear->link;
    }
    return;
}
```

I am not understanding this merging sort.

Comment: which part of this (incomplete) code you do not understand?

Comment: the actual sorting seems to happen in `mergeSort(queueFront);` but you don't show that....

Comment: Not only code is incomplete it doesn't look like a merge sort. Where is element comparison? This code does something else then name says, so it is laying to you. So this is a bad code you should not use for learning.

Comment: You have a linked list, queueFront, and a pointer queueRear to the last element in the list. This calls another function not shown to sort that list, then updates queueRear so that it correctly points to the new end of the list.

Comment: I'm confused on why we need the if and else statement.

Comment: The `if` case is when the list is empty, i.e there's nothing to iterate over to find the end of the list, and the `else` case is for a non-empty list and traverses the whole list looking for the end. You could rewrite this without the 'if' as `queueRear = queueFront;` `while(queueRear != NULL && queueRear->link != NULL) queueRear = queueRear->link;` and no if-else but then the != NULL check in the while is only really relevant for the first iteration. I wouldn't worry about that too much.

Comment: In the `else` code you have you don't actually need to reset queueRear to be the start of the list assuming that the sort did not add or remove elements; the new queueRear should be somewhere in the list still and you can traverse the list from wherever that ended up rather than explicitly going back to the start.

Comment: The `return;` is useless

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this function is the main `mergeStort` entry point. It calls a helper function (also called `mergeSort`) to do the actual sorting. But it looks like the helper function doesn't set `queueRear` correctly, so after calling the helper function, this function has to set `queueRear` to point to the last entry in the queue (or `NULL` if the queue is empty).